# How do I chain multiple promises while iterating an array after the initial promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, bluebird

I have a function(`buildMetaData`) which does the following

```
1. It receives an array(`items`) as a param
2. It invokes an DAO to fetch some data from a downstream service.
3. The downstream service responds with a promise (initial promise).
4. In the "then"(resolving initial promise), I need to modify the array passed in the param and return the modified array.
```

In Step 4, I map the `items` array, while modifying the array element, I need to call another function which returns an array of promises. I need to resolve this promise in order to set the array element.
How do I chain this array of promises to the initial promise?

```
buildMetaData(items) {
   return checkoutDAO.get(items[0].id)
      .then((order) => {
          return items.map((item) => {
              let res = {};
              // some processing 

              const promises = this.buildItemMeta({itemType: item.type, itemId: item.id})

              promises.spread((product, media) => {
                res.size = this.getItemSize(product, media);
              });
              return res;
          });
      });
}

buildItemMeta({itemType, itemId}) {
    const promises = [
      productDAO.get(itemType), // this is a promise
    ];
    promises.push(mediaDAO.get(itemId`)); // this is a promise
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

I want the new new array to have the `res.size` property to be resolved, but in reality promise.all is creating a new promise instance instead of chaining to the initial promise.

p.s. this project uses `continuation local storage`(cls), cls has some known issues with async/await, so I cannot use async/await to solve this issue.

Please let me know if this needs further explanation. I appreciate any efforts to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This performs the steps, but in an order that makes for sense asynchronously. Thinking procedurally may not be the best way to think about solving an asynchronous problem when one cannot use `async/await`. Please let me know if you have any questions.

So this:

1. It receives an array(`items`) as a param
2. It invokes an DAO to fetch some data from a downstream service.
3. The downstream service responds with a promise (initial promise).
4. In the "then"(resolving initial promise), I need to modify the array passed in the param and return the modified array.

Now becomes this:

1. It receives an array(`items`) as a param
2. It retrieves the metadata for each item and saves the array of created Promises
3. It stores the promise from the call to the downstream service.
4. All Promises are resolved
5. The 'then' is passed the item meta data and order that are used as the final stage where they are combined

Please note I've also simplified some of your code too.

```js
buildMetaData(items) {
  const itemMetaPromises = items.map(item => this.buildItemMeta(item.type, item.id));
  const orderPromise = checkoutDAO.get(items[0].id);
  Promise.all([...itemMetaPromises, orderPromise])
    .then(data => {
       // data[0] = itemMeta([itemType,itemId]), data[1] = order
      //combine order and items here
    });
}

buildItemMeta(itemType, itemId) {
    return Promise.all([productDAO.get(itemType),mediaDAO.get(itemId)]);
}
```

Here is a mock implementation to show the output.

```js
function buildMetaData(items) {
  const itemMetaPromises = items.map(item => buildItemMeta(item.type, item.id));
  const orderPromise = checkoutDAO.get(items[0].id);
  Promise.all([...itemMetaPromises, orderPromise])
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
}

function buildItemMeta(itemType, itemId) {
  return Promise.all([productDAO.get(itemType), mediaDAO.get(itemId)]);
}

checkoutDAO = {
  get: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('order')
  })
}
productDAO = {
  get: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('product')
  })
}
mediaDAO = {
  get: () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('media')
  })
}

items = [{
  type: 'itemType',
  id: 'itemId'
}, {
  type: 'itemType',
  id: 'itemId'
}, {
  type: 'itemType',
  id: 'itemId'
}, {
  type: 'itemType',
  id: 'itemId'
}];


buildMetaData(items);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get the general idea of your approach. I tried to modify my code as you suggested, but `itemMetaPromises` is resolving to an array with one object even when the `items` array has multiple items. I am not sure if that is due to something wrong with what I did. can you please help me with that?

Comment: Without knowing or seeing your complete codebase it is impossible for me to tell you what might be wrong. The best I can do is mock the moving parts to show you the output. Here, there are four items and four items are in the output.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was using `Promise.spread` from the bluebird library, that was for some reason overriding the final `itemMetaPromises` array. After changing it to `then` it started working.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.